# bsdtar: How to avoid overwriting existing file info?

Tags: tar, gnu, bsd

`bsdtar` has a `-k (Do not overwrite existing files)` option, which avoids changing the contents of any existing files, but it still overwrites the file info (e.g. permissions) with what is in the archive. Is there a way to make `bsdtar` completely skip overwriting existing files leaving file info intact the same way the `--skip-old-files` option works in GNU tar?

Here is a script that demonstrates the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo -e "\nCreate an archive with normal files"
rm -rf test-tar
mkdir test-tar
echo "TEST CONTENTS 1" > test-tar/1.txt
echo "TEST CONTENTS 2" > test-tar/2.txt
ls -la test-tar
bsdtar -czf test.tgz test-tar

echo -e "\nChange contents and permissions of one of the files"
echo "MORE CONTENTS" >> test-tar/2.txt
chmod 000 test-tar/2.txt
ls -la test-tar

echo -e "\nUntar the archive with -k (Do not overwrite existing files). The file contents are intact, but the file permissions have changed"
bsdtar -xzkf test.tgz
ls -la test-tar
cat test-tar/2.txt

echo -e "\nUntar the archive without -k"
bsdtar -xzf test.tgz
ls -la test-tar
cat test-tar/2.txt
```

Here is the script output:

```
Create an archive with normal files
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 rbrainard  wheel  136 Nov 29 17:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  14 rbrainard  wheel  476 Nov 29 17:53 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 rbrainard  wheel   16 Nov 29 17:53 1.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 rbrainard  wheel   16 Nov 29 17:53 2.txt

Change contents and permissions of one of the files
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 rbrainard  wheel  136 Nov 29 17:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  14 rbrainard  wheel  476 Nov 29 17:53 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 rbrainard  wheel   16 Nov 29 17:53 1.txt
----------   1 rbrainard  wheel   30 Nov 29 17:53 2.txt

Untar the archive with -k (Do not overwrite existing files). The file contents are intact, but the file permissions have changed
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 rbrainard  wheel  136 Nov 29 17:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  14 rbrainard  wheel  476 Nov 29 17:53 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 rbrainard  wheel   16 Nov 29 17:53 1.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 rbrainard  wheel   30 Nov 29 17:53 2.txt
TEST CONTENTS 2
MORE CONTENTS

Untar the archive without -k
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 rbrainard  wheel  136 Nov 29 17:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  14 rbrainard  wheel  476 Nov 29 17:53 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 rbrainard  wheel   16 Nov 29 17:53 1.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 rbrainard  wheel   16 Nov 29 17:53 2.txt
TEST CONTENTS 2
```

My `bsdtar` version is `3.3.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that this is a bug. I cross-posted it to  [libarchive-discuss](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/libarchive-discuss/BhIj9G2tC2g/gYNs21eYDAAJ) and one of the maintainers responded as such. Filed an issue at: https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/972